# How can I use the "http" module in koa?

Tags: javascript, node.js, koa

I am trying to use http.request on node using the koajs framework.  Is there a way I can utilize it as show below?

```
var http = require('http');

var result = yield http.request(options);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably the problem you're facing is that `http.request` takes a callback rather than returning a promise, so you can't `yield` it from koa. You need to wrap `http.request` in a function that returns a promise and hook the promise resolve into the callback, while also hooking the promise reject into the error handler.

```
function request(opts, body) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    body.pipe(http.request(opts, resolve))
    .on('error', reject);
  });
}
```

...later in your koa function...

```
var response = yield request(opts, body);
```

There are so many possible variations on this that I couldn't come close to listing them all, but that's the basic idea :)